# Let user select COM port during installation and save selected COM port in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, installation, wix

I have a web api that handles device connected to COM port.
I created simple installer using isWix that just copies builded app to location specified in installer window. How to add next step where it searches all COM ports that are used and gives user select box to specify where device is connected? I want to change appsettings.json file (one of files that are copied to instalation destination) so it has name of port selected by user.

I'm not sure how isWix is related to Wix. I think that it's a tool that just automatically creates wix project? I can use only Wix if it is not possible or it is just simpler than using isWix.

Comment: Put the settings file somewhere writable for the user and do this detection on appliation launch after installation?

Answer (score 0):

IsWiX has project templates and graphical designers to accelerate WiX development.  There is nothing in it that solves this specific problem other then by uncommenting one line of XML injects a custom dialog.  On this dialog you could then author a combobox.  You'd need to write a custom action  to populate a temporary table to have the list of COM ports and other custom actions to update the JSON file with the value selected by the user.

Is there any way this functionality can be shifted to first run of your application?  It would greatly simplify the installer design.